# Unable to set "Always Refresh from Server" in IE8 Developer Tools

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie-developer-tools

Weird problem with IE8 developer tools. I'm unable to set the "Always Refresh from Server" option under Cache. The option is NOT disabled(greyed out). Anybody else experiencing this? Thanks in advance.   My config - Windows 7, IE8 (8.0.7600.16385).

**Update:**
This seems to have been resolved in Internet Explorer version 10.0.92.

Comment: I have the same problem too.

It's not specific to a particular website, i.e. it doesn't matter what site is being viewed in the browser, I can never get this setting to turn on. I used to be able to select this option just fine, it's just stopped working in the last couple of weeks. Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: Sort Nick but no luck. The only thing that changed in last couple of weeks was that I installed the latest auto updates from MS.

Comment: Can you be specific about what exactly happens? I assume you're saying that you're clicking the menu item but the checkmark doesn't appear? Are you using 32bit IE or 64bit? Have you changed either your Protected Mode settings or your tabProcGrowth settings away from the defaults?

Comment: You assume correctly. The issue remains with either 32 or 64 bit. I haven't changed any settings in IE. TabProcGrowth is empty(default). Problem remains whether or not protected mode is on or off. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a workaround.

Go to Tools\Internet Options, then click on the Settings button in Browsing History, then select the Every time I visit the webpage radio button.

Answer (score 1):

I've been bitten by this as well and reproduced it on clean VMs, for Windows 7 32 bit as well as 64 bit. The problem occurs as soon as the "Cumulative security update for Internet Explorer", KB 2497640, is installed.

I haven't been able to find a workaround except leaving the system unpatched (not a good idea, really). What I do is running IE8 either in XP mode or in some other VM. XP and Vista are ok as a base in a VM, they don't have this bug.

Answer (score 0):

### No solution to this problem but workarounds exist

Two have been outlines in previous answers. Let me provide my own:
When I'd like the option *Always refresh from server* to be enabled I do a ***Clear browser cache for this domain*** which will force the same thing for the next request. It will get it from the server.

#### But as mentioned, these are all just workarounds.